# Where is the event sales_order_save_before dispatched?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, sales, dispatch

I am tring to figure out when sales_order_save_before is dispatched but I do not see it in the source.

What class is responsible for dispatching this event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event **sales_order_save_before** is been dispatched when an entity of Sales Order is been saved.

The class which is reponsible for dispatching **sales_order_save_before** event is the model of order **Magento\Sales\Model\Order**. In order to get to the dispatch statement, you need to look for the **beforeSave** method into inheritance heirarchy of this model. If you do so, you will end up in **Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel** class which contains the save, beforeSave and afterSave methods.

```
public function beforeSave()
{
     if (!$this->getId()) {
         $this->isObjectNew(true);
     }
     $this->_eventManager->dispatch('model_save_before', ['object' => $this]);
     $this->_eventManager->dispatch($this->_eventPrefix . '_save_before', $this->_getEventData());
     return $this;
 }
```

Just above the return statement in **beforeSave** method the eventManager is dispatching this event by concating the **eventPrefix** which is sales_order for Order entity declared in its Model class.

Comment: Thank you for the full explanation. Marking yours as correct I do not want to mark my answer as correct.

Comment: Thanks Man @logic4life

Answer (score 1):

I have found that this event are dispatched in Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel.php

```
    /**
     * Processing object before save data
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function beforeSave()
    {
        if (!$this->getId()) {
            $this->isObjectNew(true);
        }
        $this->_eventManager->dispatch('model_save_before', ['object' => $this]);
        $this->_eventManager->dispatch($this->_eventPrefix . '_save_before', $this->_getEventData());
        return $this;
    }
```

As you can see its dynamicly created at this line

> $this->_eventManager->dispatch($this->_eventPrefix . '_save_before',
>   $this->_getEventData());